# Searching a 2D array of binary Data

Tags: algorithms, optimization, search-algorithms

I'm working on optimizing the structure of an optical meta device.
I have a randomly generated 2D matrix, where 0,1 represents the presence/absence of a hole.
Each structure manipulates light differently, thus giving rise to a unique spectrum.

The problem I wish to solve is to maximize the efficiency of this structure. Given the large size of the solution space ($2^{100}$ in this case), it isn't possible to simulate each structure. Is there any search method I could use to complete this optimization?

A general workflow would be:

1. Generate a random hole structure
2. Flip one or some bits (based on the optimization algorithm)
3. Compute the spectrum
4. Go back to step 2 and make a decision based on the previously computed spectrum.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wzBN.jpg) a link to a sample hole array.

Apologies for the vague statement of the problem.

**The objective function to score a structure:** Thank you D.W. for pointing this out. The problem is of course meaningless without an objective function. I'd initially omitted it in the question, so as to not make it irrelevant for this forum by adding too much physics.

The system has a transmission $(T)$ and a reflection $(R)$, so a good objective function would be:

$\mathcal{L} = min(T) - \alpha*max(R)$

Maximizing $\mathcal{L}$ would Maximize the Transmission while minimizing the reflection.

Based on the suggestions in the comments, I did try out a Genetic Algorithm Approach (basic algorithm given below)

```
for iterations:
    for batch_size:
        flip n bits in the structure randomly
        compute objective function

    structure = structure with the highest objective function value in the batch
```

However, though there is a slight increase in the Objective function initially, it saturates quickly and doesn't reach the expected values (Image below **X-Axis** - Iterations, **Y-Axis** - Objective Function Value).

[image: X-Axis - Iterations, Y-Axis - Objective Function Value]

I have tried multiple values of batch size, bitflips (n). Is there any alternate algorithm or any possible modification to the current algorithm?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what you are trying to do, is identify a small number of matricies (2d arrays) that represent the different solutions in the solution space?

Comment: Correct! However, the main bottleneck being, each extra structure I simulate will cost me more time.

Comment: how will you use each structure? Some usages will be totally different when flipping 1 or 2 specific bits, while other uses would not change at all

Comment: Do you have an objective function?  i.e., a function that given a candidate structure, can compute how "good" it is?  Maybe you can compute the spectrum and then compute the efficiency from the spectrum?  Can you please [edit] the question to describe that function in as much detail as possible?  What properties does it have, what form does it take, etc.?  The answer will likely depend on the nature of that function.  In general, for a completely arbitrary function, the problem is not solvable, so any solution will have to exploit some regularities or properties of that function.

Comment: @D.W., I hope the subsequent edit I added answers your question.

Comment: @nirshahar, point well received. That is also a very relevant issue to consider. Some bit flips may have a very high impact on the behavior, while some will barely change it. This will depend on multiple attributes like the position of the bit, the state of the surrounding bits, etc. But that is part of the optimization challenge.

To describe the problem, there's an optical source coupled to a waveguide through this matrix. The main goal is to maximize the transmission and minimize reflection and loss from other surfaces.

Comment: Im not really sure how $T$ and $R$ depend on your hole matrix $M$, but you can try to use a genetic algorithms-like method:
Generate a starting (or a few starting matricies) matrix $M$.
Generate new matricies from $M$ by flipping random bits in it.
Take the one that maximizes $L$ from the group you just created, and iterate this process a few times.

This should give a pretty good approximation for the maximum if $L$ is a "nice" function

Comment: Thanks for the edits and responses!  Some preferences on usage of this site: There's no need to use "EDIT:", as we have revision history.  Instead, we'd prefer that you revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.  Also, rather than answering in the comments, we'd prefer that you revise the question to incorporate all relevant information; you can then flag those comments as 'no longer needed'.

Comment: Regarding your edit, your question is defined in terms of T and R, but you haven't defined T or R or how they depend on the hole structure.  Please define all notation in the question, and again, please describe how those depend on the hole structure (does that function have any regularity? any properties? hopefully it is not a completely arbitrary function).

Comment: Do you want to find one solution that maximizes the objective function?  Or do you want to find a set of solutions that are somehow as "different" as possible or "cover the space of solutions" as well as possible?  If the latter, how do you propose to measure "different" or "coverage"?

Comment: @nirshahar I did try out the GA approach as you'd suggested. I've updated the post with the results

Comment: @D.W. I just need a solution that's 'good enough'. I don't need to rigorously solve it, as that's not the goal of the research. Thus the need to measure 'difference' or to worry about covering the entire solution space doesn't arise. At the same time, if there is a good way of measuring 'solution space coverage', that would be a welcome addition!

Comment: Unfortunately I need to repeat my prior comments.  Despite the edits, the question still does not tell us anything useful about the objective; it could still be anything.  Telling us that the objective is $T - \alpha R$ doesn't help because we don't know how $T,R$ depend on the contents of the matrix.  As such, your question simply amounts to "I have a discrete optimization problem; how do I solve it?".  Such a question is not usefully answerable; all we can do is point you to standard basic resources on optimization and let you study them.

Comment: Without knowing the objective function or its properties or regularities, there is no basis for choosing among any of the many techniques for discrete optimization.  I appreciate that it may be too difficult or complicated to describe it here; if so, the question just might not be a suitable fit for our format.

Comment: If you can't give specifics of your particular situation, I wonder if you would do better to ask a new question that is more general and more likely to be useful to others in the future?  e.g., something like "how do I choose among the various optimization algorithms for combinatorial optimization?"

Comment: @D.W. sure! I'll do that. It'll be difficult to describe the complete physics of the problem!